# Spring MVC Portlet : form not saving data correctly

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, liferay

i am doing this tutorial:
http://proliferay.com/form-submit-in-spring-mvc-portlet/

Everything works but the very last part.
On my PC, the Customer form correctly displays. But if I set details of a customer into the form, when I validate the form, the customer does not get saved.
Consequently, the next jsp (success.jsp) does not find the saved Customer customer and thus displays a new one with null data.

The only difference between my version and the tutorial is that I had to build the project from Maven but this should not change anything??

Monitoring confirms that data are correct into form.jsp as I can get correct answer with :
System.out.println("\ncustomer : " + request.getAttribute("customer") + "\n");

Here are class.jsp:

```
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

    <%System.out.println("\ncustomer : " + request.getAttribute("customer") + "\n"); %>


<portlet:actionURL var="submitFormURL" name="handleCustomer"/>
<form:form name="customer"  method="post" modelAttribute="customer" action="<%=submitFormURL.toString() %>"> <%-- onSubmit="displayParams"> --%>  


    <br/>
        <table style="margin-left:80px">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="firstName"></form:input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="middleName">Middle Name</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="middleName"></form:input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="lastName"></form:input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="age"></form:input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="address">Address</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="address"></form:input></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

and the corresponding controller method:

```
 @ActionMapping(value = "handleCustomer")
        public void getCustomerData(
                @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,
                ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse,
                Model model) {

            log.info("#############Calling getCustomerData : post form validation##########");

             System.out.println("\nModel : " + model);
//displays : "Model : {customer=null null,............."



            System.out.println(customer.getFirstName());
            System.out.println(customer.getLastName());
            System.out.println(customer.getAddress());

            actionResponse.setRenderParameter("action", "success");

            model.addAttribute("successModel", customer);
        }
```

Any idea what could prevent it to work?? 
Thx in advance

Comment: Where is declaration of <form:form>?

Comment: I believe he needs to send some sort of post or put response to the spring mvc backbone...

Comment: sorry, added in edit. I missed them in my previous copy paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using Liferay 6.2+, if so than you should set (Spring is not namespacing parameters - see [SPR-11176](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11176))

```
    <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
```

to liferay-portlet.xml

```
Element : requires-namespaced-parameters
Set the requires-namespaced-parameters value to true if the 
 portlet will only process namespaced parameters. The default 
 value is true.
```

Description is taken from http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_2_0.dtd

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you so much for this one. It made the trick :)

Comment: I'm glad your problem is solved. Per portlet specification, parameters must be namespaced and Liferay (from version 6.2) changed it's behavior towards it. But for backward compatibility they introduced this (requires-namespaced-parameters) setting.

Answer (score 0):

Few things that come to my mind you can try:

change this

```
model.addAttribute("successModel", customer);
```

into this

```
model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
```

---

Instead of using `name` and `modelAttribute` you can use this : `commandName="customer"`

---

Maybe the missing space after `<%@` can be the problem?

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

Comment: same results for both suggestions